# reactJS adding a object array to and object within an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I got a response from a REST call, which returns and array with objects

```
response.data.steps
```

For example it looks like this

[image]

Now I need to add to each Child of this array an new Object Array.

What could be a smart solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to make a copy of the returning array?

Comment: Do you want to return each item as an array or add a new array property to each item?

Comment: adding a new array to each item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add a new array property to each item, you can simply do:

```
const steps = response.data.steps.map(step => ({
  ...step,
  newObjectArray: [],
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can usee [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do so

```
let result = response.data.steps.map(element => {
    let ret = [element];
    return ret;
});
```

```js
let arr = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}];

arr = arr.map(element => {
    let ret = [element];
    return ret;
});

console.log(arr);
```